# Where are you from and what do you do?

Tags: location, map, jobs, social-network

So, I've gotten to know quite a few of you at this point, and I know where a good few of you work from.  Luckily I've been able to meet up with a few people for lunches and all.  Every time I'm glad I met the person.

So, in order to continue building this network, I propose we map out where everyone is from and what you do.  Sort of like our own little sound professional directory.

I'm a sound recordist and sound editor, and I live in Orlando, Florida.

Comment: Do I sense a Google Earth .kml coming up?

Comment: How did you meet with and have lunch with Gary Rizzo? Was he in Orlando or were you in L.A.?

Comment: Colin, it was found on another topic I originally created that it makes more sense to ask these community questions on behalf of the community wiki as it is after all a common subject we are all equally interested in, as opposed to more targeted questions we regularly post on this board. No biggie, just spreading the word ;)

Comment: Jay - as nerdy as that might sound, that might be a really cool resource :-) 

Comment: Ryan - Gary was here doing a seminar on Re-Recording and education for the Apple Distinguished Educators workshop here in town. I happened to be working the event, so I made sure to get to know him a bit. Really, really nice guy!

Comment: Justin - Indeed, an interesting point

Comment: @Colin Hart - I visit my folks in Poinciana a couple times a year, would love to meet up and put a face to the name one of these trips!

Comment: @Steve - Always into meeting more sound people.  Lots of cool stuff to record around here!  Let me know when you're around next

Comment: Hey @AGZFX, thanks for introducing yourself! There's actually already an old thread like this, I will merge your question with it. 

Answer (score 10):

Beginning sound designer/editor/student in Burbank, CA.

The question title also reminded me of this. Sorry....

[youtube]rzukGfdgPCM[/youtube]

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rzukGfdgPCM

Comment: haha, nice!  :-)

Comment: haha, brilliant!

Comment: I thought there was something familiar about his wording. Thanks for that!

Comment: I immediately thought of "Who is your daddy and what does he do". lol

Comment: Haha me too!  First line that popped into my head.

Answer (score 7):

Cool concept, Colin -- thanks for initiating!

I'm a sound designer for films and video games, and live in Burbank, CA.

Comment: and a damn good one.

Comment: @Jay - The wife and I will be out your way mid-October. If you've got the time, we'd love to meet up with you.

Comment: @Steve - would love to meet up. Let's be in touch via Facebook or LinkedIn.

Answer (score 7):

I live & work in Wellington, New Zealand

Film Sound Designer, Supervising Sound Editor
http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0695670/

FX Recordist & Sound FX Library Publisher
http://hissandaroar.com

Blogger
http://www.musicofsound.co.nz/blog

Occasional musician
http://dub45.com

Answer (score 6):

I live in Falls Church, VA (DC metro area), and work at an independent production/distribution company.

My job is kind of cool in that I get to be a jack of all trades as far as audio goes: location and acquisition, and everything associated with post of course.  Lately it's been a lot of short stuff for corporate clients and fixing other peoples' programs which aren't in any sort of broadcast spec.  But we're gearing up for a new non-fiction series which I'm just itching to start.

Comment: @Shaun Farley - we should get together for happy hour / lunch sometime!

Comment: @Steve Urban - I'm in. I see you're at Post-Op media. I'll drop you a line sometime there.

Answer (score 6):

I'm from France, but I left when I was 17. Lived in a bunch of countries and at the moment I'm based in South Africa. I'm aiming to get to NYC where my girlfriend lives.

Most of my paid work is for recording and editing sound effects for features and commercials. I also do some sound design, mixing, location recording, programming and lecturing... basically I do a bit of everything. If someone phones me up and I can do the job and I have time, then I do it. I really do enjoy all aspects of sound!

What would be awesome is if I could create interactive media all the time! I would love to do more of is create art installations, and use Max/MSP and Arduinos and general physical computing. I really enjoy programming and geeking out. This is the kind of stuff I really enjoy! I'm thinking to do a Ph.D so I can delve deep into all this.

Comment: Hurrah! I've met so few sound people who are also closet academics like me. Tried to do a PhD a few times but money never permits me.

Comment: Hey Andrew, do you ever come back to the country? :)

Comment: @ianjpalmer haha! It's weird, cause I usually hate academia, but I love being in an environment where I can research my own interests and develop my own specialties independently from the pressure of earning money. It's an awesome space to experiment and be encouraged to do so. However, I'm much more interested in the technology side of all this then concepts and theories... I'm looking for a place where the projects have more value than the thesis. And where grammar is less important than the outcome! 

Comment: @Justin which country? France? My family is there so I do visit every now and then. Depends how far I am. When I was doing my Masters in Edinburgh, I would visit quite often. I see you spent 3 years in Edinburgh, was that at the University of Edinburgh? 

Comment: @Andrew I have to say I love both worlds. However, the MA I did had a particular ethos that I really like. Theory imforms practice and practice informs theory. The two are in a symbiotic relationship and shouldn't be treated otherwise.

Comment: @Andrew nah I was at Napier University. Didn't do the film school though, just regular multimedia and decided to specialise!

Answer (score 5):

Great idea, Colin.

I'm a recording engineer/composer/sound designer in Chicago. At my day job I record and mix radio and TV commercials, and at my "second job" as a freelancer I am a sound designer and composer for theatre and independent films.

Answer (score 5):

I'm a boom operator and location sound man, from Cape Town,South Africa, now living in Zurich.
Starting off my career as a sound designer by doing short films, animation and motion graphics.

Answer (score 5):

Resident ADR Mixer, Sound Designer and Re-Recording Mixer in Los Angeles.

Comment: Hey @Ryan, I'm heading out to LA in mid-October. If you've got time I'd love to meet up with you.

Comment: @Steve It's mid October.

Answer (score 5):

I'm a recording engineer/sound designer/composer in Auckland, NZ. I'm in-house at an ad agency, so mainly work on commercials for TV/radio/online. I work on short films too, when time permits.

I haven't been too prolific in posting here yet, but still learn a lot from everyone's fantastic contributions.

Answer (score 5):

I'm a budding Effects Editor/Sound Designer from Limoges, France.

I spent 3+ years in Edinburgh, Scotland, where I attended uni for a Digital Media course but ended up specializing in film sound with an academic-year-long project, among others. I'm a bit lost as to where I should start looking for work but it's ok :)

EDIT: this is a brief update to signal that I am now living in Paris, working at a dubbing company encoding videos for On Demand diffusion.

Comment: I'd love to work in the sound post crew on french films. From the films i've seen, the soundscapes are so textured (even though i hate using that word) and detailed. But my french c'est pas bien...

Comment: Ha ha, I just went to the cinema 5 hours ago to see a French movie. It was also the first time I went alone, and I paid so much more attention to the details than when I'm accompanied... But then I hate it that I only get to see silly French overdubs of 98% of the movies on Earth...

Comment: Ahhh yes. One of the french voice artists i work with told me that they record their dubs in a strange way: the words come up on screen and are stretched to represent how fast/slow they're delivered, and you have to hit them when the moving line hits them... a lot like karaoke.
Which is just crazy, because then the actor is too worried about hitting the words at the right time to deliver a good performance!

Comment: See, I saw that on TV a while ago, I didn't even imagine it would be the French standard way of working... well, at least we're left with some good French movies when they do get made!

Answer (score 5):

If my E3 change of status is approved; sound editor and recording engineer in NYC. Mainly foreign language dubs for obscure tv shows, plus whatever indie shorts and features i can get my hands on.

If not; freelance sound assistant/editor and audio assistant in Sydney, which would involve chasing the big boys for some work and probably calling up my friends at Channel 9 and asking for some shifts.

Great thread, good to hear what everyone does!

Answer (score 5):

Cool Thread!

Right now i'm in Barcelona doing all sound gigs at a small production studio, but i'll be very soon moving to new york to be an assistant at harvestworks media arts centre. They're a school/studio/research lab. Can't wait!

Comment: Nice one! Drop me a message if you want some sound people to hang out with in NYC, if i'm still here that is!

Comment: @Filipe That's what I wanted to do! I was there last year doing a ton of their courses... awesome place! I should be back in NYC this fall, so will give you a shout then. 

Comment: @Sound I will for sure, thanks!
@Andrew That's actually very reasurring! Please Do give me a shout!

Answer (score 5):

Hi, great idea !
I'm a sound designer, sound editor. I work for video games and films. And live in Lille, France.

Comment: Hi @emarque, may I ask where you work? Is it in a studio or are you a freelancer? I have the opportunity to go to Lille next week, I thought we could try to catch up.

Answer (score 5):

I'm in Arlingon, VA and work as a sound editor / mixer / designer for TV and radio (with the occasional indie flick)

**:EDIT:**

I'm no longer in VA. I recently celebrated my first full month in LA, and I can still pay all my bills doing sound! Let's hope this trend continues...

Comment: Steve, I reckon this post should be yours and not the community's, after all it's your work, if people like it then it makes you more popular. Again, no rule, I'm just trying to make the best use of the site's features ;)

Comment: Eh, perhaps. But it seems what's been done can't be undone: if I go into edit there's no wiki box to un-check. Besides, I'd rather earn reputation from my big brain with it's various pockets of knowledge, sarcasm, and ignorance than from where I landed and built up a career. It's a different kind of reference point as to where my knowledge comes from, and due to that I'll make it community knowledge.  Like that? I just made it up on the fly...

Comment: We're not computers after all, and interpret things our own way. That makes for a colored community, let's keep it that way :)

Answer (score 5):

Hey! I'm Alan Senderowitsch, sound designer and composer from Buenos Aires, Argentina.

I do freelance work for film & tv and I have a band of electroacoustic music focused on real-time improvisation.

[myspace.com/alansende](http://www.myspace.com/alansende)

Answer (score 5):

I am just starting a job as the resident sound designer at Pioneer Theater Company in Salt Lake City, UT as well as an Adjunct Professorship at University of Utah teaching sound design.

Up 'til now I have been freelancing in Portland, OR in sound design and editing for corporate video, indie films and theatre.

Be sure to look me up if you're in SLC!

Comment: I AM in SLC!  Coffee?

Answer (score 5):

I'm a Sound Designer and Dubbing Mixer. Originally from deepest, darkest Wiltshire in the sound of England but now working Galway, Ireland. Trying to move back to the UK though (London, Manchester, Cardiff in case anyone knows of any work going).

Ian

Answer (score 5):

Sound designer and voice actor, Live in Norway but my work is all over the world.

Comment: @Glenn X. Govan I like this "...my work is all over the world."

Answer (score 4):

I'm an aspiring sound designer for films and games going to school in Milledgeville, GA. I'm still just reading the books and learning all I can about the discipline. I also want to get more into computer stuff.

Comment: @Mercy Ah.  Are you in the GCSU digital media program?  Milledgeville has some beautiful old assylums, btw :)

Comment: No, but I'll look at it.

Answer (score 4):

I am also a Colin (yay for Scottish roots).  I had lived in Atlanta, Georgia for most of my life, but just relocated to Portland, Maine.

My day job is as an A/V technology specialist - I deal with corporate and live A/V systems with a focus on video conferencing/streaming technology and control interface programming.  I do a some video and audio editing for the corporations that employ me.  I also freelance as a FOH or M1 mixer in local venues when I get the chance.

During the nights, weekends, and every spare moment I do work as a dialog editor and sound designer for primarily independent films.  My wife and I also team up to work as production sound recordists with me at the controls and her on the boom.  We also write and produce when we have time in between sound-related work.

I am relatively new to film sound and it's been an awesome learning process.  Thanks to resources like these, I'm constantly expanding my understanding... thanks, you guys and gals!

Comment: +1 for Portland, Maine! My brother and his family live nearby in Scarborough, and I'm originally from a little town just outside of Bangor.

Comment: M1 mixer means Monitor mixer? That's one of the most dangerous jobs out there.

Comment: Cool!  I'm going to Bangor for the first time later this month for the film festival. 

@Ryan Yes, M1 is monitor mixer.  I love it.  You get to manage lots of mixes instead of just one :)  And have musicians yell at you...

Comment: @VCProd Yeah - and watch out for feedback :)

Answer (score 4):

Having grown up in Maine (like @birdhousesound and others here!), I'm the design director and co-founder of an interaction design and development studio in San Francisco. As such, I produce interaction, visual, motion, and sound design for software.

I've had a long history in the video and post-production industries, and as such have been using ProTools on and off to 20 years. Yikes...

Comment: Yay for New Englanders!

Comment: I second that!!

Comment: I'm from Northern Cali!

Comment: I'm from New England but now live in Northern Cali, best of all worlds! :-p

Comment: @Noise I was born in Corte Madera. Then moved to Sac. Now in LA. :-}

Comment: Right on, @Ryan, I live in Marinwood, just north of San Rafael.

Answer (score 4):

I've been working as Sound Designer / Editor / Mixer for over 16 years, first in Buenos Aires, Argentina, then in Mexico City and now settled in Toronto, Canada. Here I share my passion for everything audio with picture and Visual effects editing.
If you need something from the north... gimme a holler :)

Answer (score 4):

I'm a composer and sound designer, in Salt Lake City, UT.

To pay the bills, I program medical simulators for a nursing school.

Answer (score 4):

Nice one Colin! Very different from the usual questions but so interesting to find out where all of you are in the world and what you are doing exactly.

So, I'm English but living in France. I'm currently in the south but soon moving to Paris where work is more abundant. I edit and design sound mostly for media agencies (adverts, online videos, virals etc) and I am getting more and more addicted to field recording!!!

Comment: @Colin Hunter whereabout in the south of France? :)

Comment: @Justin...I'm currently in Avignon for the summer. Been looking for work around Marseille but so far to no avail. Hence the move to Paris (where I have more contacts)...where do u come from?

Answer (score 4):

I am a lecturer in sound theory, production and design at Edinburgh Napier University.  I started out as a live sound engineer, FOH and M1, and moved into theatre sound design.  After that I started teaching and doing whatever sound work comes my way, currently it is mostly research.

Answer (score 4):

I am everything about sound. From recording to mix..  from sound design to music...  this is typical in Taiwan. My company is specialized in making animation in 90 minutes. SO we people here are pushing the limit in every seconds. TOUGH!

Comment: Are you familiar with 30 second bunny theater? Not the best example of sound design, but it popped into mind when reading your response. 

Answer (score 4):

Hi there,

Lots of interesting people out there. What a great community and Andrew, thanks for this site!!!

I am a foley artist originally from Canada who now lives and works in South Africa. I also do field recording and sound editing. I have done a few stints in dialogue recording and editing but it is definitely not my specialty. I love all areas of sound for film, TV, radio and games. I think we are all lucky to be working in something we are passionate about.

Thanks for this site!

Answer (score 4):

I am an alien from outer space and I moved to San Francisco to go to audio engineering school at SAE Institute where I discovered Sound Design.

Answer (score 4):

Nice to meet you all. I'm a sound design, filmmaker, teacher and author of "Sound Design: The expressive power of music voice and sound effects in cinema." Currently living in Los Angeles area, giving webinars on sounddesignforpros.com, more stuff on SonicStrategies.com. Come visit, and I look forward to more interaction with everyone. Thanks Andrew and Colin for getting us together like this.

Comment: Hey there!  Great to see you here!  Can't wait for the seminar next week!  How did the one today go?

Comment: It went well for me, very deep information.

Comment: Everyone here should buy David's book.  It is an excellent and informative read.

Comment: _THE_ David Sonnenschein??? Oh my god, I´m a big fan of yours! I did thesis about audio sound design in commercials and used your book as a backbone to the whole thesis! Absolutely love your book, it really definitely changed the way I think about sound design and helped me eventually to get a job in sound design field. I cannot recommend more highly the book David has written. There´s no other book like it! 

Answer (score 4):

Hello - I'm from the Netherlands, living/working in the south of England (Brighton). I mainly do sound effects design for video games (usually iPhone, PSN/Xbox Live kind of games, so fairly small scale stuff so far). I'm freelance, working from home - I love that! Occasionally I also produce music + sound effects for promo videos. Most likely I'll be working on my first feature film this winter (doing sound design), so that's an exciting prospect.

Because of all the great blogs and sites like this, I've over the last few months become extremely interested and enthusiastic about location recording, so I'm doing more and more of that these days, trying to integrate it with my daily work routine.

Answer (score 3):

Queens, NY ova heeah. I make stock and custom sound libraries and soundscapes for visual artists and musicians. I also do some sound art pieces of my own and a whole mess of field recording. Fun thread!

Answer (score 3):

Great Idea for a thread! We should try this on some other forums...

Myself? Composer/Sound Designer/Engineer/Gadabout from Ottawa ON, Canada. Currently serving as Chief Engineer and Studio Manager at Atomic Audio doing TV Shows, Indie Films and lotsa Government Videos.

Answer (score 3):

I'm originally from Michigan.  About twenty minutes north of Detroit.

I'm an in house Sound Designer for a video game developer in San Diego.  You can here some of my work on Transformers: War for Cybertron.  I've been in the industry for about five years now.

Answer (score 3):

I teach group music classes to pre-kindergarten children (ages 6 weeks to 5 yrs). I live in Toronto, studied Electroacoustics at Concordia in Montréal, and theatre at Queen's University in Kingston, Ontario.

I've composed and designed sound for a couple dozen indie theatre productions - but lately, I've sort of fallen out of love with theatre. Shhhh, don't tell her.

Gestating my first album.

Answer (score 3):

Bay Area working in a staff position as a sound editor/designer (with the occasional stint as a music editor) for films. Just relocated a couple years ago after a 10 year run in LA working first in commercials, then feature film.

Answer (score 3):

Really interesting thread.

I grew up in Connecticut and Maryland, I'm half American and half French. I spent a lot of time in Pittsburgh but have lived for nearly four years in Edinburgh, Scotland.

I guess I'm a sound artist, doing a lot of sound installations and interactive music and sound systems. I also occasionally still gig as a musician, and I have a company that makes iPhone apps and things like that.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a Music Tech student in Edinburgh, UK. Focusing my last year around sound design and game audio and hopefully joining the industry asap after I graduate next year!

Feel free to hit me up if you're in Edinburgh, I don't have many sound design buddies up here :) joe.cavers @ gmail.com

Answer (score 3):

80% of my work time is split between dialogue editing and mixing, film or tv series, as a freelance in Rome, Italy.

20% is soundfx editing/design, I love it... and try to make this my first job

Answer (score 3):

I am a freelance sound designer/editor/mixer for film and video games currently in Columbus, Ohio.

I am also a member of a theatre company here, as an actor, but when our sound guy can't do a project I will sometimes pick it up (mixing a musical next month for example).

Most of my clients are in a different state.

(Currently working on a high profile independent video game, a AAA video game, and a full length independent film.)

Answer (score 3):

Hi there!

René Coronado - lead sound designer at Dallas Audio Post Group

I came here straight out of school in Dec of 1999, and have grown up with the company.  I love living and working in Dallas because its a great sports town (we work with the Stars, Mavs, and Rangers - working on the Cowboys), a good production town, and your money goes a long way here compared to other places.

60% of our work is from out of town, with big chunks coming from DC and LA.  I've personally cut ADR for Cats and Dogs 2 that's coming out, The Last Airbender, and of course we do all of the ADR for the network shows that are being shot in town (including The Good Guys, Midland, etc).  We also recorded both George and Laura Bush's upcoming audio books for Random House, so business is good!

We're a right to work state, so no unions here - which means that I have to triple count my blessings with regards to the company I work with.  The founder, Roy Machado really lives up to his promises to keep us engineer folk the best equipped and best paid in the region.  We're also set up like a law firm, so after x number of years engineers become vested partners in the company.  We're always consulted on gear and procedures, and its rare that a need doesn't get filled.

I'm not a musician, but Roy and Brad are and they are some of the best.

On the side, I shoot video and timelapses with my Canon 7d, and I always have my Sony PCMD50 on me to record the world around me.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a Sound Designer/Editor in Buenos Aires, Argentina. Primarily, we work on Films and TV shows at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

I live in Pasadena, CA. During the day I record and mix TV & Radio spots at Juice Studios in Santa Monica. Use to do more sound design in the past but continue to build my library daily. I currently sell fx on a few different sites but I'm hoping to create a site along the same lines as Chuck Russom & Tim Prebble in the future.

Great thread.

Answer (score 3):

Hi there!
Michel Marchant here from Santiago de Chile ( No, I'm not french)
I have worked many years in Santiago, and Mexico City doing sound effects editing and mixing for TV commercials.
After a while my wife and I decided to move to Montreal, Canada and I started doing sound design and field recording for video games at Wave Generation.
If one of you guys happen to be visiting the city, drop me an email
Beers on me
Cheers,
M

www.mich3d.com

Comment: Are you French? :D (You really don't have to answer again...)

Answer (score 3):

Just started doing freelance sound design for short film here in New York. Originally from Bangkok, Thailand. weeee

Comment: Chai! Lau nee..

Answer (score 3):

I am in Virginia Beach, Virginia working in the field of Audio for a major Television company. I do audio post work when I am not doing live shows. I have developed into a all around audio engineer through the years and I have been very blessed to do a lot and learn a ton. I truly love what I do and could not imagine doing anything else. Not sure where it will take me from here but I am always open to things. BTW this is an awesome site and I am very glad I found it.

Answer (score 3):

I am a boom operator/sound editor living at my company MISOSound in Los Angeles, still starting out in the world of sound. My partner and I mostly work on films and documentaries, but we've done a couple of video games now and are trying to break into that more as well.

Answer (score 3):

Hi everyone, I work as assistant sound editor for movies, mixer and sound editor for tv shows and audiobooks. Also, as a freelancer, doing anything related to our world of sounds. It happens that the market isn't very good here at Rio de Janeiro, Brazil.

Answer (score 3):

And a hello from Thessaloniki, Greece. I run a recording studio for music mainly, but have been getting involved in production sound and sound design for film and theatre as well. I enjoy all aspects of sound related work, but the creative soundtrack design for moving images seems more fascinating at the moment. This is a nice community - keep it up!

Answer (score 3):

Hey, My name is James Bretz and I'm from Bellingham, Washington.   Started my own company, Auddity Sound, when a friend asked me to do the post sound on his film about a year ago. So now I do free lance sound design, production sound, post production, and still try to record and mix bands when I can and sprinkle in a live recording here and there.  It's not full time yet... but soon.

Answer (score 3):

Hi guys, this is my first post.  I really like the way this site has come together.

I'm in Chicago.  I am a sound designer\composer in experimental and traditional theatre, and day job as a full time sound engineer at a local Chicago theatre.

-Chris

Answer (score 3):

Living and working in San Francisco
Doing mainly commercial and short film work.
Heavily interested in multimedia audio, video, physical computing, alternative control.
It's great to see some Bay Area folks around!

Comment: 415 represent! :-)

Answer (score 3):

Hi,

I am originally from Canada now residing in South Africa. I am a foley artist and sound effects editor and presently doing a lot of field recording throughout SA to capture all the sound that make up this country. I have worked in the field for 20 years now.

Great to see so many people corresponding and networking. Thanks Andrew for starting this.

Answer (score 3):

I live and work in NYC.  I'm been working in Radio for 10+ years and have dabbled a bit in post and game sound as of late.  I've been on the content and technical side of radio production, mostly working for NPR shows in the US.  During that time I've also been a recording nut.

I also run this SFX company:  http://rabbitearsaudio.com and this Blog: http://sepulchra.com/blog/

I'm an avid road and track cyclist and love food.

Answer (score 3):

I am from the Netherlands, living in Munich, Germany now and doing sound design at BMW (the car company).

My background is in Industrial Design, with a master towards sound design.

Besides some music and sound stuff for various small projects, I haven't achieved much yet, I am very much a newbie. So I eagerly soak up all the knowledge and expertise that is shared in this community!

Answer (score 3):

I'm in Winnipeg, Canada.  I've had a lifelong fascination with sound, and have been messing with synths, samplers, and DAWs for the last 15+ years.  I only recently started investigating the world of proper sound design (i.e. outside of making sounds with a focus on music) and field recording, and I am completely hooked!

I recently helped a friend out by making a few sounds for a really cool game project and I am very hungry for more work like it.  I currently work as a software developer, but my ultimate goal is to somehow make a living working with sound because it's my true passion in life.

This site and its contributors have been an essential part of my learning experience, so thanks very much to all of you for sharing so much useful information.

Comment: You could probably combine your passions and develop awesome audio software.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a long time Game Audio guy from LA (near Burbank) trying to rebuild my traditional post clientele again.  I work out of my home and other studios.  I seem to gravitate toward animated projects, but not on purpose.

Answer (score 3):

Alreet!

I am currently Lead Sound Designer at Radium Audio in London.  I mostly do broadcast, digital and branding but we're getting into live installations these days as well.

Started out playing the drums and wanting to be a rockstar! Eventually that wore off and I fell in love with sound design instead, which seems to be working out so far.

I'm new to this site, and loving it.  Really nice interface and I can see myself going a bit Pokemon for the badges.  Good to see such a diverse mix of people on here as well :)

Cheers

Chris

Answer (score 3):

I am a budding sound designer based in Launceston, Tasmania (Australia).

My day job is varied as I run a new media company. I produced podcasts, consult on new media/trans-media. Lecture sometime for AFTRS and other places. I have worked on feature films and shorts as either sound technical assistant or sound recordist. Occasionally I also produce projects (video games, short films, radio). Basically I am a jack of all trades, but love sound.

Started working in sound about 15 years ago but always mixed it with my other passion of technology. My main claim to fame is producing one of the longest running pop culture podcasts in the world, [(Cool) Shite on the Tube](http://coolshite.net) (don't listen if you are afraid of some naughty language and un-PC commentary). I am also the technical director of [Supanova Pop Culture Expo](http://www.supanova.com.au) (the Comic-con of Australia).

Loving this site. Heaps of great information and people. You all rock!

Answer (score 3):

hello

we're not alone, great to read all these intro's!

I'm from Amsterdam, netherlands
Started locationrecording on features, documentary, TV. Over the last years Music / Sounddesign work became my main focus. I work on Animation, Films, Commercials, Artstuff

Answer (score 3):

I wish I'd known about this site much sooner. I'm a freelance location sound mixer/boom operator/sound utility for film and television based in Albuquerque, NM. I used to edit radio for a number of years and work out of my home production suite before I met a great sound mixer (and great friend) David Brownlow, who helped me get involved with film.

I'm originally from NYC, born and raised in the bronx and moved to Brooklyn right after high school, plus lived in Florida for a short time years back. I fell in love with sound as a kid through music, and I think I love sound more than music today. I've been fortunate to work on a few great films, TV shows, and some Docs with great people and learn great things. This site is my new great place to listen and learn. Thanks for making this possible.

E. Santiago

Answer (score 3):

HI - I'm from Guatemala, living/working in Barcelona! 
Musician and sound designer! In my free time I'm trying to build an audio library of old/new mayan musical instruments for Kontakt and Ableton sampler!! Great community here, saludos!!

Comment: @Juanca,  Great city! I lived there for a little while and plan to go back to visit soon. I'll give you a shout! Best of luck. 

Answer (score 2):

Nice one! 
I'm a location sound recordist and also sound designer. I live in Nicosia, Cyprus.

Best regards

Comment: I had a buddy who was stationed in Cyprus -- or just off the coast -- in the US Navy.  He said it was beautiful (but the girls were crazier than Americans).

Comment: Hey Dave i just saw your comment. Sorry for the delay. it is actually a beautifull island nad yes your buddy is right. Girls here are crazy!

Answer (score 2):

Hi all,

I'm a born and bred Johannesburger, in South Africa and I work as a location sound recordist, whilst playing about with animation on the side!

I've worked feature films as a boom operator and also worked as a sound mixer on one low budget feature.  Mostly though, I do commercial shoots, documentary shoots and corporate shoots.
I'm keen on learning to do final mixing and foley recording and building up my sound library!

This site is great, I find it much more user friendly in comparison to many other forum sites and the knowledge I have gleaned in the last few days of browsing the site has been great!

Thanks for everyones inputs!

Answer (score 2):

I am a freelance sound recordist and designer from Belgrade, Serbia, with over 10 years experience in television, film, radio and theatre.
this is my site: http://cvrgoje.com

Answer (score 2):

I'm based in Las Vegas, Nevada USA doing sound for casino games as well as some commercial and indie film post.  I started in Detroit, Michigan and moved west in 1996, started my own studio in 2003.  Love this site!  John.

Comment: Love this site? Where have you been?! :D

Answer (score 2):

Great post! It's awesome to see the huge amount of diversity on this forum!

I'm currently living in Reston, VA about 30 minutes outside of DC.

I'm working at a church as one of their audio technicians. One of my responsibilities includes acting as the broadcast mixer for the Saturday night and Sunday services.

I haven't done much Sound Design work since college, but perusing this forum and other blogs and twitter feeds has whet my appetite to work on some stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Hello all fellow sound guys!

I am from Thessaloniki Greece but currently living in Athens Greece.

I started my studies as a sound engineer stayed for 4-5 years around Greece and then i decided to make my dream come true and started Tsimpountiii Games. I do all the composing / sound / game design there for our games. And working on many many more projects including directing, sound programming, sound design, field recording, photography ... and the list goes on...

You can check all of my work here http://www.tsimpountiii.com

Answer (score 2):

Hi Folks. I'm a sound engineer from the UK now living in Macau and working on The House of Dancing Water theatre show by Franco Dragone. I'm also a sound recording artist, and progressing in that field, making "cinema for the ear" multi channel recordings and installations. My piece 'Airtight Orange Plastic Coffin' will be presented in a completely dark cinema environment at the Walter Reade Theater / Film Society of Lincoln Center in New York City next April as part of 'Unsound', a festival of experimental music and sound art.
If any of you New Yorkers are interested, let me know and I'll give you more details.

Nice to (virtually) meet you all.

Answer (score 2):

Hey, im living Perth Western Australia, mostly boom operator location sound recordist and mixer for tv. The job is somewhat quite varied which always keep you on your toes.. In the meantime volunteering for film makers for sound and ever expanding my own library. lol

Answer (score 2):

I wish I was a sound designer, but at best I reckon I'm just an audio post guy. I also still freelance as a boom op and sound recordist. Currently shuttling between Melbourne, Australia and Singapore. Anyone else from these parts?

Answer (score 2):

I'm a freelancer from Uppel, The Netherlands and mainly work as a location sound- recordist and designer for documentary films. ( www.geluidsvormgeving.nl )

I'm also a sound-artist and performing technician in a jazz band. (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UhwTsW2w0nE )

Mark Thur

Answer (score 1):

I am a final Year film school student in India.I have worked in small fictions and documentaries & have done some mixing in dolby digital formats.
Thank for the website
cheers

Answer (score 1):

Hello SSD. Jon Tidey from Vancouver, BC.
Freelance Engineer, Editor, Producer, Blogger, Podcaster and now sample library creator. I work from my home studio primarily with music but I'm fascinated by sound design and I love the way it changes your perspective on the world around you. I'm in awe of what you guys can do, I know it's not easy.
I have learned a ton in my short time lurking on SSD and I'd like to thank you all for sharing your knowledge.

Recording Blog & sample libraries = http://audiogeekzine.com

Hire Me = http://epicsounds.ca

Podcast = http://homerecordingshow.com

Answer (score 1):

Hello! I´m a audio producer and sound designer, in Helsinki, Finland. Been in the audio biz for ten years and I´ve recently branched out to gaming audio. I´ve got a BA in digital audio and commercial music and currently work at Remedy Entertaiment as an Audio trainee.

update: Now working as an sound designer in the same company

Answer (score 1):

Hi - I'm an in house sound designer/composer for a company in London.  Nice to see a great mix of people on here, I'm new but I definitely should to stick around!

Also, any other sound designers here from London? Drop me a message..

Answer (score 1):

Im from Pune, India. Studied from SAE. I work in Mumbai/Bombay in a company called Words Infocom. since 1yr as a dubbing engineer and mixer, dubbing disney cartoons, other tv series in foreign and regional languages. I have also been a foley recordist on a regional language film. Im also a music recordist/editor and worked on a project involving recording a fusion band for 2 months. We have 5 studios with Protools 8 le and HD Setups with ICON in 1 of them and 8 engineers working in shifts.

In my previous job as a trainee in another city, i editted sound effects for a film and tv series.

Looking for a better paying job and opportunity to work on films and also plan to study sound design abroad but its very expensive

Answer (score 1):

I'm a sound designer primarily for video games in Vancouver, BC. The day job is being the sound guy for Klei Entertainment.

Answer (score 1):

Hi, my name is Guillermo Ursini. I am recordist and editor for film tv and radio in Argentina. I am very interested in learn more about sound for film and work in florida USA.  Please see my web page www.estudiou.com.ar

Good year for all the pros! Bye bye!

Answer (score 1):

Hi all! I'm a sound editor and re-recording mixer in Sweden.

I spend my time pretty evenly divided between film and Tv, editing and mixing.
I also work with a great composer doing the score music mixes for the features he works with.
When i'm not sound geeking or recording weird sounds I love the odd moment of silence and of course I'm also a long time sail bum.

Answer (score 1):

Music composer from Paris / France. I'm interested in the marriage of sound and music. The musical expressiveness of sound, or the noise of music. :)

Answer (score 1):

Well
It seems that the army of the sound designers is already gathered and counted. Now we should go to CA and capture Skywalker Ranch.

Answer (score 1):

Sound editor/designer in Hollywood California.

Started cutting on film using a Moviola when as a sound editor you had to know how to do it all. Dialogue editing, sound FX, Foley, ADR, backgrounds etc. 
It gave you the broad view and an understanding of how everything worked together. A great way to learn.

Worked non-union at first the way you did back then. 
It was a huge deal to get in the Union. Very excited when I got in. The MPSE was actually kinda difficult to get in back then too. Now ... not so much.

Work pretty much exclusively on feature films.

http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0039810/?ref_=fn_al_nm_1

Answer (score 1):

I am a chatty Karol.....I am a dialogue mixer, ADR mixer, Dialogue editor....me loves the chatter. I live in LA.

Comment: Do you also *live* in LA? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Hey All,

Great question (and site) @Andrew!  I live and work in Toronto, Canada as an sonic gun for hire. I get to wear a ton of hats from SFX supervisor to mixer to ADR director to sound designer. Every so often I get called upon to write some original music, but not so often that I bill myself as a composer. In addition the post audioness of my life I'm also writing and pitching some projects for TV with a partner. It occurs to me that I may have an issue with focus.

Every once in a while I update my blog here:
http://www.adbofdifference.com/blog/

Answer (score 0):

Working as dubbing/ADR, mixing engineer and dubbing supervisor at Prime Focus in Mumbai, India

Earlier worked as a Dubbing, Mixing, Foley, Asst. Music Recording Engg in a mid-size company in Mumbai working mostly on tv projects. Graduate d from SAE, Chennai. Avid gamer and films enthusiast and sound designer in  free time.

Fluent in Protools 10 HD with ICON & Nuendo 4. 
Working since 2 years

Answer (score 0):

I'm a theatrical sound designer/engineer living/attending school in Philadelphia PA.  I'm currently sound designing a production of How to Succeed in Business without Really Trying for school, and on the look out for more opportunities - Philadelphia sure isn't NYC in terms of theater jobs.  Great thread!

Answer (score 0):

I live in London England, I'm sound mixer and engineer (which means I do everything sound orientated in this place) mainly mixing adverts, promos and tv shows for a terrestrial TV station.

I'm also recording, designing and mixing short films when and where I can, in the hope to better myself and move into the film industry.

I also co-run a sound studio in central London which is part of a new production company.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a student currently living in Dubai, UAE hoping to get into film and game sound, I'm going to be starting film school in Jan 2012 in Auckland, NZ. I guess I could say my mindset about working in sound is pretty immature like I think it would be cool and funny if someone shoved a hydrophone up their butt and farted, I even got Mr. Nick Maxwell The Ableton Tutor to create something with [my brothers fart](http://soundcloud.com/nickmaxwell/swirling-death-vortex) for fun haha (I know it sounds like it but I don't have a fascination with flatulence). I'm just trying to experiment and have fun with sound until I actually end up working on something of importance, I've just been doing this for a year now just reading and doing research and building my knowledge and experience.

Recently I've been helping a [friend](http://www.dylan-ellis.com) at his studio he's been nice enough to sort of mentor me and give me real experience on producing music, its really been great in helping me be more serious and in showing me how hard you need to work to get projects done and things.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a sound editor/designer in Los Angeles, CA under the moniker/company Stavrosound.  I supervise some shows, while serving as part of a crew on other shows.  Additionally I own Simultaneous Contrast, a new sound effects library offered presently through Sounddogs.com, still growing at about 3,800 assets to-date.  I love going out to record new material at every opportunity.

I am a dialogue editor by trade (and fiercely at heart), although I have been in high demand lately for BGz, EFX, and Design work.  It sort of ebbs and flows like that.

Answer (score 0):

Phil Ensminger, Minneapolis, MN.  http://philensminger.com/about/

I am currently a student in Audio Production with a concentration in audio for video at Hennepin Technical College.  I'm just entering the post-production industry, taking as many projects as I can get my ears on!

I absolutely love this forum....as a resource, an outlet, or just good topical reading!  Keep it up!

Answer (score 0):

Nice to meet you all i'am Shantos Ssekito a production/ location sound recordist /mixer and live in Kampala, Uganda, East Africa and am so damn passionate about what id do, i have worked on feature films, documentaries, talk shows, reality shows, short films and i double this up also as a crew fixer in most African countries plus Location scouting so you might say am jack of all trades feel free to drop me an email at shantos2010@yahoo.com anytime for a quick professional chat

Answer (score 0):

My name is Jamie, from Melbourne Australia.
mostly i am doing location sound stuff at the moment.
but hoping to do more and more post sound stuff, in the second half of this year.

Answer (score 0):

Hi, I'm Fred and I'm an aspiring Sound Designer.

I studied Sound Technology at LIPA in Liverpool, UK, before moving down to London and running at Hackenbacker for a year. I'm now running at Envy and I run a royalty-free sample library called Arrowhead Audio (http://www.arrowheadaudiosfx.com).

I love SSD and visit regularly, mostly reading it rather than posting and this thread is a fantastic idea. It's nice to read about what all you guys are doing!

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

@Andrew its nice to know that im not the only one who run away from his country very young, lived in few countries and has an addiction to max/msp, i know the feeling too well ;)

Answer (score 0):

i studied sound design in UK, but i always consider my self a student. love max/msp and love to use it even in my current not so creative job. Lived in few countries and now im japan working as audio editor and engineer for a podcast company.

Answer (score 0):

Hello All,

I have been a follower of this forum for a little over a year now, but only recently began participating it more.  It is a great resource and thanks for creating this additional directory.

I am a sound designer, re-recording mix engineer, ADR/Narration/VO engineer, sound editor, and part-time composer working in NYC.  I went to Berklee and have been in NYC for the last 5 years.

As we all know, working can suck and there days when I just don't want to do it, but then I remember that I just get to mess around with audio all day. And even though (at least in film and visual media) it is often an over-looked and under-appreciated aspect to the finished product, I have begun to notice that filmmakers and producers understand its value.

Thanks to a great community!

Answer (score 0):

I am from Seville, Spain.

I do freelance work in almost every sound area:
Location Sound, Sound Edition & Post-production & Sound Design.

http://javierzumer.com/en/

Answer (score 0):

I'm a theatrical sound designer from Brooklyn, NY. http://www.jeremyb.com

Answer (score 0):

Hey!

I'm a student in the UK studying Sound Design and New Media, hoping to be an Acoustic Consultant, Sound Designer or Voice Actor!

Best of luck to everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I missed this one!

I'm a freelance Sound Editor/Re-recording Mixer based out of Los Angeles working on projects ranging from short and feature films, TV shows, commercials, game audio, and web content. I also occasionally work on location recording dialog or FX, and have spent time doing FOH, orchestral recording, DJing, and video editorial/engineering.

Answer (score 0):

Im a sound maker from Stockholm, Sweden. Freelance in film and builds interactive experiences and applications within Max/Msp. I Love simplicity, silence and computers.

Booya!

Comment: hej! whats sound design industry like in Stockholm?

Comment: Hej! Just moved to Stockholm to study so I don't know that much about Stockholm just yet. But seems to be. Well. Ok? Yes I've got a good feeling 

Answer (score 0):

Hey everyone! Recordist/Sound Designer/Mixer/ADR/Musician (Pretty much anything that has to do with sound I enjoy!) I'm coming from Seattle, Washington however have currently situated myself in San Francisco, CA. I'm a student getting my bachelors. However, I'm trying to get all the necessary gear and needs to start my creation of a professional sample library which I will deliver online. Besides that aspiration, I do almost all the sound for my friends student films down here in SF to start building my show reel.

BTW I'm available to contact if anyone people in the Bay Area wanna meet up for a recording session at some location to start building those sample libraries! :)

Best,
MichaelBrennan

Answer (score 0):

I'm a Sound Designer/ADR Engineer/Mixer from Dallas, TX. My company is Okratron 5000 inc.

We handle mostly VO for video games & ADR dubbing for japanese animation & foreign films. With lots of design/mix for picture in the gaps. Really enjoying the forum & I look forward to sharing thoughts with all of you.

Answer (score 0):

Jacob Paul Proctor here from Salt Lake City, Utah. I was shocked to see others from SLC on here! David sonnenschein too, his book is really good! I got my audio engineering education from the Los Angeles recording school, and worked at various studios out there before moving to Utah and starting my own studio. It's a pleasure to meet you guys!

Answer (score 0):

Hey, I'm an aspiring Sound Designer/Location Recordist in Portland, OR. It's a bit slow here right now because of all that darned rain, but at least it gives me something to record.

Answer (score 0):

Hi all,

My name is Pasi Pitkänen and I'm a composer & sound designer from Tampere, Finland. I have Bachelor degrees in 'Digital Sound and Commercial Music' from Tampere University of Applied Sciences and 'Creative Sound Production' from University of Abertay Dundee. I currently work as a sound designer at Rovio Entertainment Ltd.

Website: http://www.pasipitkanen.fi/

Twitter: https://twitter.com/pasipitkanen

Facebook: https://www.facebook.com/pasipitkanenfi

Cheers,

Pasi Pitkänen

Answer (score 0):

Freelance sound designer/composer, currently working for the ABC (Sydney-Australia) as a promo maker for radio.

Do audio post for TVCs on the side, and write music when I can.

Answer (score 0):

Hello from Atlanta, GA.

Freelance Sound Editor/Location Mixer with music performance/composition on the side. Over the past few years, I spent a lot of time filming in central america and now focusing on post sound for film/television. Always looking to strike a balance between field recording and working behind monitors!

[www.stevehornesound.com](http://www.stevehornesound.com)

Answer (score 0):

I'm from the North-East of England.

I studied Music Production and Sound Engineering.  Mainly a hobbyist now but get the odd job now and again.